# MySQL use REGEXP with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a database with two tables. The first table has a single column which contains regex expressions (there are about 200 rows). The second table has multiple rows and I would like to get all the rows from the second table that matches all the regex from the first table.

For example, if the first table has:

```
^google.com/orp
^amazon.com/ssw
^stack/ik9
```

and the second table has

```
stack/ik9282
msifks0
amazon.com/ssw9a
```

the result should be

```
stack/ik9282
amazon.com/ssw9a
```

I have tried to do this using `GROUP_CONCAT` and get the regex from my first table as `^google.com/orp|^amazon.com/ssw|^stack/ik9`, but `GROUP_CONCAT` has a maximum length of 1024 and I need more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT strings.value
FROM strings
JOIN patterns ON strings.value REGEXP patterns.pattern;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a625ea0748b8187b47c747afc0a28f98)

---

> `GROUP_CONCAT` has a maximum length of 1024

You may adjust [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) variable setting.

Comment: Thanks! How can I modify it such as I will get the rows that are not matching the regex? I actually need a query to get what matches and another one to get what doesn't match.

Comment: @tatulea . . . That is not the question you asked here.  This answers the question that you did ask.  You can modify this answer using `left join` and `where` to get the values that don't match.